# Get data from two tables using one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a social networking page and want to get all the user's activity on a feed page.

I have a comments table:

```
user_id    comment                date
1          "Hi...."               24 March 2013
2          "Hello..."             25 March 2013
1          "Another comment..."   26 March 2013
```

And a likes table:

```
user_id    id_of_liked_item     date
1          101                  24 March 2013 
1          145                  25 March 2013
```

Is it possible to perform a single query to get these into an array of all a user's activity, ordered by date? If so what would that query look lik? My array would need to look something like this:

```
$activity = array(
    array(
        "type"=>"comment",
        "content"=>"Comment goes here"
    ),
    array(
        "type"=>"like",
        "item_id"=>345,
    )
)
```

I'm quite good at manipulating php data, so I probably don't need much help organising the array, but my question is mainly how to get the data from the database in the first place. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a UNION is the way to go:

```
SELECT 'comment' AS Type, Comment AS Content, NULL as Item_ID, Date
  FROM Comments
  WHERE User_Id = 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'like', NULL, id_of_liked_item, Date
  FROM Likes
  WHERE User_Id = 1
```

That will give you a result set that looks like this:

```
Type    Content            Item_ID Date
------- ------------------ ------- -------------
comment Hi....             null    24 March 2013
comment Another comment... null    26 March 2013
like    null               101     24 March 2013
like    null               145     25 March 2013
```

And you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would probably be to use a union:

```
SELECT
    'comment' AS type,
    comment AS content,
FROM comments
UNION
SELECT
    'like' AS type,
    id_of_liked_item AS item_id
```

You can of course also add `WHERE` conditions and additional columns to each query in the union for organization by user.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT `user_id`, `comment` AS activity, `date` FROM comments

UNION

SELECT `user_id`, `id_of_liked_item` AS activity, `date` FROM likes) 

AS user_activity

ORDER BY user_activity.`date`
```